# What is this scenario of denying responsibility called?

Tags: phrase-requests

What is this scenario called?

Someone says something or tells you to do something or wants something but nothing goes as planned. They completely blame the other person, saying it was all their idea, deny everything they ever said, and try to turn it around as if it was the other's fault.

I hope there's a word.

Answer (score 2):

I think one definition for this person is [double-faced](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/double-faced):

> - duplicitous; hypocritical. (American Heritage® Dictionary)

Comment: [Apparently,](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=you+two-faced%2Cyou+double-faced&year_start=1840&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cyou%20two%20-%20faced%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cyou%20double%20-%20faced%3B%2Cc0) ***double-faced*** did have some currency in this figurative usage a long time ago, but it sounds odd to me by comparison with ***two-faced***. But OP's context could embody many things, including *buck-passing* and [*psychological projection*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychological_projection)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - it does not sound odd to me, and actually no dictionary says it is outdated or out of common use. ***Double-faced:*** Tending to say one thing and do another; deceitful:
were you double-faced—did you betray them? (ODO).

Comment: I suppose it's pretty obvious *double-faced* doesn't sound odd to you, or you wouldn't have posted it. And I'm not claiming the usage is in any meaningful sense "wrong" - just nowhere near as common as *two-faced*, as my NGram link shows.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I don't understand your point. If you have a better answer post it please.

Comment: I voted to *close* the question, because it's not clear to me exactly what aspect of the situation OP is interested in (duplicity, blame avoidance, whatever). But the point of my first comment was simply to make the point that (used figuratively in this way) *double-faced* is far less common than *two-faced*. If OP updates the question text to clarify that duplicitousness is indeed the specific quality he's looking for, I'll happily upvote your answer (having already called attention to the alternative term for the same thing). But as yet that hasn't happened.